# Filter partial dependencies by effect size

Tags: r, dependencies, mlr

I fitted a model and want to take a look (and plot) at the partial dependencies.
For this task, I use the `mlr` package. However, since I have 80 features I only want to look at those with the highest effect on the target variable. Is there a way to calculate or show the partial dependence only for the features with the highest influence?

Here is an example: I just fitted 4 values. Let´s assume I only want to look or calculate the partial dependence for the 2 most influential features.

```
library(mlr)
pd = generatePartialDependenceData(mod, train_task, c("diveyTrue",  "dinnerTrue","BikeParkingTrue", "latenightTrue"))

pd
PartialDependenceData
Task: dat
Features: diveyTrue, dinnerTrue, BikeParkingTrue, latenightTrue
Target: diveyTrue, dinnerTrue, BikeParkingTrue, latenightTrue
Derivative: FALSE
Interaction: FALSE
Individual: FALSE
   review_count diveyTrue dinnerTrue BikeParkingTrue latenightTrue
1:     73.92993 0.0000000         NA              NA            NA
2:     73.68386 0.1111111         NA              NA            NA
3:     73.68386 0.2222222         NA              NA            NA
4:     73.68386 0.3333333         NA              NA            NA
5:     73.68386 0.4444444         NA              NA            NA
6:     63.56335 0.5555556         NA              NA            NA
... (#rows: 40, #cols: 5)
```

The task is a regression and the first column is the target variable. All other variables are dummies. Therefore, the target variable stays constant until the value of "diveyTrue" is greater than 0.5.

Here is a small `dput()`:

```
 structure(list(data = structure(list(review_count = c(73.9299260484918, 
73.6838552698629, 73.6838552698629, 73.6838552698629, 73.6838552698629, 
63.5633491608329, 63.5633491608329, 63.5633491608329, 63.5633491608329, 
63.5633491608329, 44.123492893074, 44.0855985404284, 44.0855985404284, 
44.0855985404284, 44.0855985404284, 67.9185575263356, 67.9185575263356, 
67.9185575263356, 67.9185575263356, 67.9185575263356, 64.1248331786005, 
64.1243679505065, 64.1243679505065, 64.1243679505065, 64.1243679505065, 
64.9177431842816, 64.9177431842816, 64.9177431842816, 64.9177431842816, 
64.9177431842816, 58.2709529252224, 58.2709529252224, 58.2709529252224, 
58.2709529252224, 58.2709529252224, 89.8281204749236, 89.8281204749236, 
89.8281204749236, 89.8281204749236, 89.8281204749236), diveyTrue = c(0, 
0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    dinnerTrue = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
    0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 
    0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 
    0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), BikeParkingTrue = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.111111111111111, 
    0.222222222222222, 0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 
    0.555555555555556, 0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 
    0.888888888888889, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), latenightTrue = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.222222222222222, 
    0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.555555555555556, 
    0.666666666666667, 0.777777777777778, 0.888888888888889, 
    1)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002521ef0>), task.desc = structure(list(
    id = "dat", type = "regr", target = "review_count", size = 9943L, 
    n.feat = c(numerics = 79L, factors = 0L, ordered = 0L, functionals = 0L
    ), has.missings = TRUE, has.weights = FALSE, has.blocking = FALSE, 
    has.coordinates = FALSE), class = c("RegrTaskDesc", "SupervisedTaskDesc", 
"TaskDesc")), target = c("diveyTrue", "dinnerTrue", "BikeParkingTrue", 
"latenightTrue"), features = c("diveyTrue", "dinnerTrue", "BikeParkingTrue", 
"latenightTrue"), derivative = FALSE, interaction = FALSE, individual = FALSE), class = "PartialDependenceData")
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this quite easily. First you use whatever method you want to determine the feature importance, then take the top two and plot the partial dependence graphs for them. There's no single-step way of doing this.

Comment: I tried this already. I calculated the "permutation importance", sorted the values and calculated the plots based on the results. However, the features which were most influential for "permutation importance" were not the same as the features for partial dependence. The goal is to plot the target variable against each feature not the interaction of the features.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand -- how you're determining the most important features is independent of how you're computing and plotting the partial dependencies. In particular, if you're not interested in feature interactions, then simply don't take that into account when you're computing feature importance.

Comment: OK, we were talking about different things. My question is how can I get the top two features? For "permutation importance" it´s easy because there is only one value. So I can simply sort the values. For "partial dependence" it´s a little bit tricky since there is a range of values.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean now. Partial dependence is not really a measure for feature importance as the ones you would normally think of, it's more of a tool to visualize what's going on.